# Flatten JSON with drifting schema in Azure Data Factory

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-factory

Is there a way to flatten the following rather inconvenient type of JSON object in Azure Data Factory (V2)? Top-level keys in the data represent dynamically generated dates, which are different in each file. Hence, the schema is drifting.

I would like to flatten the data by unrolling the `members` array under each date key. Please see sample input and desired output below.

I haven't found a way to achieve this in a Mapping Data Flow. The *Flatten* activity does not seem to work since the schema cannot be defined, and I am not unrolling single array but many. My second attempt was to use *Unpivot* to transpose each date to a row and then flatten, but it seems that the complex type is not supported for unpivoted values.

**Input sample**

```
{
  "2021-01-01": {
    "total": 30,
    "members": [
      {
        "name": "foo",
        "value": 10
      },
      {
        "name": "bar",
        "value": 20
      }
    ]
  },
  "2021-01-02": {
    "total": 70,
    "members": [
      {
        "name": "foo",
        "value": 30
      },
      {
        "name": "john",
        "value": 40
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Desired tabular output**

|  | name | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | foo | 10 |
| 2021-01-01 | bar | 20 |
| 2021-01-02 | foo | 30 |
| 2021-01-02 | john | 40 |

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try this:

Flatten your JSON array `members` of  `2021-01-01` and `2021-01-02` separately. Then use `DerivedColumn` transformation to add date as column. Finally, union your data in two stream.

But this way need you create multiple branches. If you have lots of date object data, it will be complex.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This could work if the keys were always `2021-01-01` and `2021-01-02`. However, the keys are generated dynamically by the source system and both the number of keys and their names differ in each file. Hence, Mapping Data Flow treats them as drifting columns, which to my understanding cannot be unrolled.